# Behavior of flatMap with different Schedulers in it

Tags: rx-java2

Could you explain why I am getting strange output when I change schedulers of the returned Observable in flatMap? For example, I have

```
Observable.range(1, 9)
        .flatMap {
            if (it < 5) {
                Observable.just(it)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            } else {
                Observable.just(it)
            }
        }
        .subscribe({ println("${it}: ${Thread.currentThread().name}") })
println("END")
Thread.sleep(200)
```

As output I have different results on each run. E.g.
The first launch

```
1: RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
2: RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
3: RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
5: main
6: main
7: main
END
4: RxCachedThreadScheduler-6
8: RxCachedThreadScheduler-6
9: RxCachedThreadScheduler-6
```

The second launch outputs this:

```
5: main
1: main
2: main
3: main
6: main
7: main
8: main
9: main
END
4: RxCachedThreadScheduler-8
```

Comment: It's all about the subscribeOn() operator, when it is applied, the whole stream gets changed and switched to the passed scheduler. Maybe I'm wrong, since I checked, that subcribeOn() changes the scheduler even upstream applied subscribeOn()

Answer (score 7):

`flatMap` merges on one of the participating thread non-deterministically, thus even if the inner sources have `subscribeOn` and/or `observeOn` defined, there is no guarantee which thread will win at a particular moment to emit items from the sources. Therefore, you have to apply `observeOn` after `flatMap` if you want to ensure subsequent event processing happens on the desired thread (until there is another async boundary operator).